# on_train_batch_end takes 0.7 second, but generator.__getitem__ takes only 0.1 seconds. How to debug it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm training a CNN model that needs some complicated processing in input. I'm using `keras.utils.sequence` as a generator. I can't find a way to implement this in `tf.data`. I'm working in Colab with tensorflow 2.3 and its internal implementation of keras.

I get the following warning when training the model.

tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.2641s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.7211s). Check your callbacks.

However, I don't have any callbacks! So I'd imaging that the time is spent only inside the generator.

If I time `x,y = trainGenerator[0]` however it takes only 0.1 s. So... Where are the additional 0.6 seconds going? I tried tensorboard profiler but I wasn't able to understand it.

Comment: I am working with tf.data (even plain yield generators) and still get this error. Seems to be thrown only by tf 2.3

Comment: In your case is the warning wrong (it's taking less time than it claims) or is it actually taking that long? Because in my case it's really taking that long to process the input somehow

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Also, it is now thrown on the previous used versions such as tf 2.1